# How to compare relative location within an array?

Tags: perl

I'm using the [Graph package](https://metacpan.org/dist/Graph/view/lib/Graph.pod#COPYRIGHT-AND-LICENSE) to create a graph with four vertices, like this:

```
my $graph = Graph->new;
$graph->add_edges(qw(a b c d));
```

I want to cycle through all possible combinations of two vertices, which I'm doing with a nested loop.

```
for my $i ($graph->vertices()){
  for my $j ($graph->vertices()) {
    (statement[s])
  }
}
```

However, this results in many duplicates, such as for (a, b) and (b, a). To fix this, I would like to have a statement such that the second for loop only runs if $i is earlier in the list than $j. These aren't numbers, so a statement like  `if($i < $j)` does not work. But the program moves through the list in the same order. How do I refer to this order, or set an order and refer to it?

Edit: This might work if there is a way to compare indices of arrays in for loop. I'm not sure if this is possible, though.

Here is the full nested for-loop using the code given in the answer below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Graph;

my $graph = Graph->new;
$graph->add_edges(qw(a b c d));
my @vertices = $graph->vertices();

for my $i (0..$#vertices) {
    my $vi = $vertices[$i];
    for my $j ($i+1..$#vertices) {
        my $vj = $vertices[$j];
        my $graph = Graph->new;
        $graph->add_edges(qw(a b c d));
        my @vertices = $graph->vertices();
        $graph->add_edge("$i", "v");
        $graph->add_edge("$j", "v");
        $graph->delete_edge("$i", "$j");
        print $graph, "\n";
     }
}
```

Comment: Does the order matter in the iteration? Because [documentation for `vertices`](https://metacpan.org/dist/Graph/view/lib/Graph.pod#vertices1) reads *"In list context, return the vertices, in no particular order"*, i.e., vertices can be returned starting from *c* instead of *a*, for example.

Comment: My intention is to take advantage of the fact that the vertices are always returned in the same order (as far as I can tell) to prevent creating duplicates, because I can't find a simple way to search for and remove duplicates. (Any way to do this would require me to save the output for each loop in a distinct variable.)

Answer (score 1):

Just read all the vertices into an array, then set up your nested loop.

```
my @vertices = $graph->vertices();

for my $i (0..$#vertices) {
    my $vi = $vertices[$i]; 
    for my $j ($i+1..$#vertices) {
        my $vj = $vertices[$j];
        ...
     }
}
```

UPDATE: User said he's getting the output below

```
 0-v,1-v,a-b,c-d;
 0-v,2-v,a-b,c-d;
 0-v,3-v,a-b,c-d;
 1-v,2-v,a-b,c-d;
 1-v,3-v,a-b,c-d;
 2-v,3-v,a-b,c-d
```

Comment: The vertices are strings, not numbers. I start from _a_ and, in this case, go down the alphabet. This approach creates new vertices 0, 1, etc but leaves existing vertices untouched.

Comment: @eclare It doesn't make any new vertices actually; instead it iterates over the *indices*. If you print `$vertices[$i]` and `$vertices[$j]` in the loop, you'll see it gives you the needed result.

Comment: I am using the nested for loop to add edges $i-v, $j-v, and delete edge $i-$j. The output when using the above code is 0-v,1-v,a-b,c-d; 0-v,2-v,a-b,c-d; 0-v,3-v,a-b,c-d; 1-v,2-v,a-b,c-d; 1-v,3-v,a-b,c-d; 2-v,3-v,a-b,c-d. Since none of the vertices were originally numbers, this means that this for loop creates new vertices.

Comment: @eclare I don't understand your problem - I wrote the output above. What are you trying to achieve? It looks like you are subtracting the indices rather than the vertex at that index of vertices (if that makes sense). Add (update) to your (original)  post the code that produces this output